# jQuery Newsticker stopping on hover, starting on mouse leave?

Tags: jquery

below is the jQuery code I am using to create a news ticker found somewhere on web but Having very difficult time stopping it on hover and starting after mouse leave, kindly help me out someone. Thanks in advance.

```
function tick(){
     $('.news-ticker li:first').slideUp(
     function () { $(this).appendTo($('.news-ticker')).slideDown();
   });
 }
     setInterval(function(){ tick () }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

to stop the animation you can use jQuerys `stop`:

```
function tick() {[...]}

var timer = setInterval(function(){ tick () }, 5000);

$( '.news-ticker' ).hover( function() {
// stop function
    clearInterval(timer);
    $( this ).find( 'li' ).each( function() {
        $( this ).stop();
    } );
}, function() {
// start function
    timer = setInterval(function(){ tick () }, 5000);
} );
```

UPDATE:
Of course, if you just start tick() again, it will just runned once. to start the interval again, you just neet to set the timer again. But therefore, you need to make dome other changes, you can see above.
clear the running interval to prevent on starting the next interval the first to be continued.

Comment: Thank a lot @Mephiztopheles for the help, I will definitely use it but how would you set the interval to rotate the list, it seems that you have removed it from the equation.

Comment: Made a change for you